# weblogic deployment location

Tags: weblogic

Is there a way to find from weblogic admin console where the actual application is deployed on the file system

I tried clicking on the 'deployment' link - but it says it is loading - and never shows any details

I 'know' that the actual deployment is in a specific directory outside of weblogic - just want to know how I can confirm what I think I know - but need conclusive proof

The deployment is an EAR file 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

When you login to the admin console you should be able to click 'Deployments' on the left. On that page you should see a list of all deployments on your managed server(s). Clicking on the deployment in question will take you to the deployment overview, which lists the path.

If it was deployed with the 'nostage' option, it will be somewhere that all of the servers it is deployed to can see. With the 'stage' option, it will be copied to each of the servers and reside in:

```
<domain home>/servers/<server name>
```

If you are having trouble even getting to the deployments page I would cycle the admin server.